# Parallel ForEach on DataTable

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I would like to use the new Parallel.ForEach function to loop through a datatable and perform actions on each row.  I am trying to convert the code below:

```
        foreach(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
        {
           ...
           Do Stuff
           ...
        }
```

To this code:

```
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(dt.Rows, drow =>
                {
                    ...
                    Do Stuff
                    ...
                });
```

When I run the new code I get the error:

*The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Action)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`DataTable.Rows` returns a `DataRowCollection` which only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Use the [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) extension method on `DataTable` (from `DataTableExtensions`) instead:

```
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), drow =>
{
    ...
    Do Stuff
    ...
});
```

Comment: D'oh!  Beat to the punch (by mere seconds)!

Comment: would this same extension be available for other collections that implement IEnumerable? such as the TreeNodeCollection? or would I have to create this extension myself?

Comment: @Scott: You'd have to write it yourself - because otherwise it's not going to know which type of `IEnumerable<T>` to return, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Make sure to reference System.Data.DataSetExtensions

Comment: Note that a DataTable is not Thread-Safe. You may run into "internal index is corrupted" errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450675/datatable-internal-index-is-corrupted

Comment: got a lot of silliness myself, even lock()ing access...  thanks for the warning @Marc

Comment: The increase in process time is incredible! I went from 1m50 to 12 seconds.

Answer (score 19):

This is better than the accepted answer because this does not need to reference System.Data.DataSetExtensions:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(), dr =>
```

To use ForEach with a non-generic collection, you can use the Cast extension method to convert the collection to a generic collection, as shown in this example.

Comment: But keep in mind this, from [Cast docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx): "If an element cannot be cast to type TResult, this method will throw an exception. To obtain only those elements that can be cast to type TResult, use the OfType<TResult> method instead of Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)."

Answer (score 8):

Parallel.ForEach() expects the first argument to be an IEnumerable<> type.  DataTable.Rows is not, but you can turn it into one with the AsEnumerable() extension method.  Try:

```
... Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), drow => ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This way we can use Parallel.ForEach for Data table.

```
DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();
            dtTest.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(int));
            dtTest.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dtTest.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(int));

            DataRow dr = dtTest.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = 1;
            dr["Name"] = "Rom";
            dr["Salary"] = "2000";
            dtTest.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dtTest.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = 2;
            dr["Name"] = "David";
            dr["Salary"] = "5000";
            dtTest.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dtTest.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = 3;
            dr["Name"] = "Samy";
            dr["Salary"] = "1200";
            dtTest.Rows.Add(dr);

            Parallel.ForEach(dtTest.AsEnumerable(), drow =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ID " + drow.Field<int>("ID") + " " + drow.Field<string>("Name") + " " + drow.Field<int>("Salary"));
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify Jon Skeet's answer to make it work.

```
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable<DataRowType>(), drow => {
     drow.SomeCol = "";
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654161/how-to-use-parallel-foreach-with-datatable