# adding data rows using parallel.For

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, aggregate

I have n sets of rows in a data table and I want to add these n sets. I am looking at ways to parallelize this.

example:
Set 1: row 0 to row 9
Set 2: row 10 to row 19
Set 3: row 20 t0 row 29
Set 3: row 20 t0 row 29

Add these to another table
Total datatable (row 0 to row 9) = set 1 + set 2 + set 3

I am using C#.

Currently I have implemented this using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem as follows but it is bit ugly.

I span n number of threads (max = total cpus)
distribute sets to these threads and calculate partial sums
span n/2 threads to sum these partial sums
when I have two partial sums, then I sum them to total dataset.

example:
if I have 10 sets and 4 cpus

on first iteration

1st cpu: sum 0,1,2 = sum1
2nd cpu: sum 3,5 = sum2
3rd cpu: sum 6,7 = sum3
4th cpu: sum 8,9 = sum4

second iteration

1st thread sum1 + sum2 = sum10
2nd thread sum3 + sum4 = sum 11

third and final iteration

total sum = sum10 + sum11

I am trying to do this using .net framework 4.0 Parallel library.

Comment: Please tell us what computer language you are trying to use.

Comment: I am using c# and added more details to my question

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Patterns and Practices group has a book which details a number of techniques for parallel programming.  There is a whole chapter on Parallel Aggregation which can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx and this contains code examples in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Please see:

[Parallel ForEach on DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408557/parallel-foreach-on-datatable)

From MSDN:

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx