# Update Excel From C# Based on Column Name

Tags: c#, excel

I am looking for a way to update an existing Excel spreadsheet with data from a SQL query via C# putting data in columns based on column header.  For instance, if I have the following returned query/dataset

```
Width    Height    Length
  2        2          2     
  2        3          4
  3        4          5
```

And I have an Excel workbook like so:

```
Width    Height       Area      Length     Volume
                    =(A1*B1)              =(C1*D1)
                    =(A2*B2)              =(C2*D2)
                    =(A3*B3)              =(C3*D3)
```

I would like to insert Width, Length and Height into the workbook without affecting Area or Volume, i.e.:

```
Width    Height       Area      Length     Volume
  2        2        =(A1*B1)      2       =(C1*D1)
  2        3        =(A2*B2)      4       =(C2*D2)
  3        4        =(A3*B3)      5       =(C3*D3)
```

Is there a way to specify in code that the Width from the dataset should go in the Width column, etc.?  I am currently using the EPPlus package to do Excel tasks.

Comment: If you know the column index and you are pulling values from Entity Framework why not  'Worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = Entity.Height;' Where worksheet is the name of the worksheet and your 'Height' information is being stored in column B.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches for this 
1. You can hard-code the Excel column name's index
2. You can resolve it and put it in a dictionary

I'm going to go with option 2 so it's easier for you. However a couple of assumptions.

- You know how to get the Worksheet property of your application through Interop.Excel
- You are able to specify the row where you start entering the data, and row of where all the column names are

Here's the code

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public void SyncData(Worksheet ws, DataTable dt, int startRow){
    //Get the columns and their corresponding indexes in excel
    Dictionary<string, int> columnMap = ExcelColumnResolver(ws, dt, 1);

    //The row number in excel youre starting to update from
    int currRow = startRow;

    //Iterate through the rows and the columns of each row
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
        foreach(DataColumn column in dt.Columns){

            //Only update columns we have mapped
            if(columnMap.ContainsKey(column.ColumnName)){
                ws.Cells[currRow, columnMap[column.ColumnName]] = row[column.ColumnName];
            }
        }

        currRow++;
    }
}

//columnsRow = Row in which the column names are located (non-zero indexed)
public Dictionary <string, int> ExcelColumnResolver(Worksheet ws, DataTable dt, int columnsRow) {
    Dictionary<string, int> nameToExcelIdxMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    //The row in Excel that your column names are located
    int maxColumnCount = 10;

    //Excel cells start at index 1
    for (int i = 1; i < maxColumnCount; i++) {
        string col = ws.Cells[columnsRow, i].ToString();

        if (dt.Columns.Contains(col)){
            nameToExcelIdxMap[col] = i;
        }
    }

    return nameToExcelIdxMap;
}
```

Here's a [tutorial](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm) on how you can access the Excel worksheet

Runtime is O(n^2), but for performance I would recommend:

- [Populating the data in an object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536636/write-array-to-excel-range) and using the Worksheet.Range
  property to set a group of cells, instead of individually updating
  the cells 1 by 1.
- [Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408557/parallel-foreach-on-datatable) the writing of rows to the object
  array, since there are no dependencies between the rows

Answer (score 0):

Using **EPPlus** and assuming *GetDataFromSql* returns *DataTable*, you can use the following code:

```
var data = GetDataFromSql();

using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\Proj\Sample\Book1.xlsx")))
{
    var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

    // Get locations of column names inside excel:
    var headersLocation = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
    {
        var cell = worksheet.Cells.First(x => x.Text.Equals(col.ColumnName));
        headersLocation.Add(col.ColumnName, new Tuple<int, int>(cell.Start.Row, cell.Start.Column));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
        {
            // update the value
            worksheet.Cells[headersLocation[col.ColumnName].Item1 + i + 1,
                headersLocation[col.ColumnName].Item2
                ].Value = data.Rows[i][col];
        }
    }

    excelPackage.Save();
}
```