# How to use Parallel.ForEach with dataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

How i can use Parallel.ForEach with DataTable it works fine with List and array but i cant get it working with DataTable it shows Error "Cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly"

```
 Parallel.ForEach(dt.Rows , row=>
                {
                  //code here  

                });
```

Comment: It's not about Parallel.ForEach, it's about Rows not implementing IEnumerable

Comment: How this question get plus points?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408557/parallel-foreach-on-datatable

Comment: my question is same then why i get minus? without reason

Comment: maybe because it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that You need to cast a row with AsEnumerable() extension method:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(dt.Rows.AsEnumerable() , row=>
            {
              //code here  

            });
```