# DataTable internal index is corrupted: '5'.used in threading

Tags: c#, .net

I have used a static Global dataset shared between a number of threads.

I got the following exception :

> Data Table internal index is
>   corrupted: '5'.

In threading, I read the value from the datatable & update(used merge) the value in datatable both operation done in threading.

Comment: could you post you code please? and what line is generating the error?

Comment: what .net framework are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing operations on a dataset from different threads.

The dataset is not thread safe, you should make a `wrapper class` which protects the dataset from more than 1 operation at the time. This is called a mutex:

[link to microsoft msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx#Y2991)

A better solution is to no use global state at all. This will fix your problem without any extra work and makes your code much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using threads with a dataset, that error will occur.

In my case, I was trying to create a new row for a dataset within a method that was running in threads.

One way was to use **SyncLock** around the method that creates the row or another way (and probably even better) was to create the rows outside of threads.

Basically my code looks something like this:

```
    Dim elements As New List(Of element)
    Dim dataRows As New List(Of MyDataSet.Row)

    For i As Integer = 0 To elements.Count - 1
        dataRows.Add(Me.Ds.Elements.NewElementsRow)
    Next

    Parallel.For(0, elements.Count, Sub(i As Integer)
                                        Me.CreateElementRow(elements(i), dataRows(i))
                                    End Sub)
```

In the **CreateElementRow** method I'm doing a lot of calculations in threads.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Since you are using your dataTable in multiple threads, there is a high possibility of corruption--if you are manipulating the object from different threads.

Some pointers to help you resolve your issue :

- Avoid using Default Views, and
  modifying the Default View if
  possible. Btw, .Net 2.0 has a number
  of reader/writer locks on creating
  views, so they are not the issue they
  were pre 2.0.
- Call AcceptChanges() where possible.
- Be careful about .Select(expression),
  since there is no reader/writer lock
  in this code -- and it is the only
  place (at least according to a person
  on the usenet so take it w/ a grain
  of salt -- however, this is very
  similar to your issue -- so using
  Mutexes may help)
- Set AllowDBNull to the column in
  question (questionable value, but
  reported on the usenet -- I've used
  it only in places where it makes
  sense)
- Make sure that you are not setting
  null (C#)/Nothing (VB) to a DataRow
  field. Use DBNull.Value instead of
  null. In your case you may wish to
  check that the field is not null, the
  expression syntax does supports the
  IsNull(val, alt_val) operator.
- This has probably helped me the most
  (absurd as it sounds): If a value is
  not changing, don't assign it. For example if you want to assign value to some column do it as  :

> ```
> if (column.Expression != "some expression") 
>       column.Expression = "some expression";
> ```

Answer source : [StackOverflow - DataTable internal index is corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450675/datatable-internal-index-is-corrupted)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed my Internal index is corrupted problem:

```
System.Data.DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
for (int iCol = 0; iCol < dtOriginalData.Columns.Count; iCol++)
{
    dtNew.Columns.Add(dtOriginalData.Columns[iCol].ColumnName, dtOriginalData.Columns[iCol].DataType);
}
for (int iCopyIndex = 0; iCopyIndex < item.Data.Rows.Count; iCopyIndex++)
{
    dtNew.Rows.Add(dtOriginalData.Rows[iCopyIndex].ItemArray);
    //dtNew.ImportRow(dtOriginalData.Rows[iCopyIndex]);
}
dtOriginalData = dtNew;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using same datatable in mutiple process @ same time.. I just resolved this issues using SYNCLOCK..

try this..

```
SyncLock your datatable

'''' -------your datatable process

End SyncLock
```

Kindly let me know if this helpful to you..

Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

To prevent execution in multiple threads I used :

```
Application.Lock();
--- do your stuff in the datatable
Application.UnLock();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable.BeginLoadData();

// Do MultiThreaded Inserts

DataTable.EndLoadData(); 
DataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

this will fix your issue