# C# DataTable internal index is corrupted: '5' on Save in Windows Form

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a small form which connects to a single data source (SQL Server database) as has two bindings to two of the tables.

When inputting data:

```
Reg (A read only list box from table `vehicles`)
ID (A Read only auto generated id which increments from the max id in table 'serv')
Desc (Text input, table 'serv')
Date (Datetime picker, table 'serv')
```

If I put in data that has a date of the future it works ok, if I use a date from the past after I have previously input a record with a date from the future then I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: DataTable internal index is corrupted: '5'.

Record input testing:

- Future then Future = OK
- Past then Past = OK
- Past then Future = OK
- Future then Past = Error

I cannot figure out why this is the case on such a simple form.

Full Error:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: DataTable internal index is corrupted: '5'.
   at MYPROGRAM.MYPROGRAMDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(MYPROGRAMDataSetdataSet) in C:\MYPROGRAM\MYPROGRAMDataSet.Designer.cs:line 11240
   at MYPROGRAM.NewService.servicesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\MYPROGRAM\NewService.cs:line 50
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3260.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
MYPROGRAM
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/MYPROGRAM.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3221.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3314.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3221.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3260.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3221.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Caching
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.7.3056.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Caching/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.Caching.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Save Button Code:

```
private void servicesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegTextBox.Visible = true;
    RegTextBox.Text = regComboBox.Text;
    RegTextBox.Visible = false;
    RegTextBox.Visible = true;

    string RText = RegTextBox.Text;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("SQLCON");

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLQuery, conn);
    da.Fill(ds);

    RegTextBox.Visible = false;
    this.Validate();
    this.servicesBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.MYPROGRAMDataSet);

    bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Visible = true;
    servicesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Visible = false;

    regComboBox.Visible = false;
    serviceIDTextBox.Visible = false;
    service_TypeTextBox.Visible = false;
    service_DescriptionTextBox.Visible = false;
    service_DateDateTimePicker.Visible = false;

    MessageBox.Show("Service Saved", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    // this.servicesTableAdapter.Fill(this.MYPROGRAMDataSet.Services); (Commented out as not needed as I reopen form below)
    NewService.ActiveForm.Close();

    var newForm = new NewService();
    newForm.Show();
}
```

TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(MYPROGRAMDataSetdataSet) (Down to line 11240)

```
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "15.0.0.0")]
    public virtual int UpdateAll(MYPROGRAMDataSet dataSet) {
        if ((dataSet == null)) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("dataSet");
        }
        if ((dataSet.HasChanges() == false)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (((this._consumablesTableAdapter != null) 
                    && (this.MatchTableAdapterConnection(this._consumablesTableAdapter.Connection) == false))) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentException("All TableAdapters managed by a TableAdapterManager must use the same connection s" +
                    "tring.");
        }
        if (((this._employeesTableAdapter != null) 
                    && (this.MatchTableAdapterConnection(this._employeesTableAdapter.Connection) == false))) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentException("All TableAdapters managed by a TableAdapterManager must use the same connection s" +
                    "tring.");
        }
        if (((this._holidaysTableAdapter != null) 
                    && (this.MatchTableAdapterConnection(this._holidaysTableAdapter.Connection) == false))) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentException("All TableAdapters managed by a TableAdapterManager must use the same connection s" +
                    "tring.");
        }
        if (((this._servicesTableAdapter != null) 
                    && (this.MatchTableAdapterConnection(this._servicesTableAdapter.Connection) == false))) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentException("All TableAdapters managed by a TableAdapterManager must use the same connection s" +
                    "tring.");
        }
        if (((this._vehiclesTableAdapter != null) 
                    && (this.MatchTableAdapterConnection(this._vehiclesTableAdapter.Connection) == false))) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentException("All TableAdapters managed by a TableAdapterManager must use the same connection s" +
                    "tring.");
        }
        if (((this._damagesTableAdapter != null) 
                    && (this.MatchTableAdapterConnection(this._damagesTableAdapter.Connection) == false))) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentException("All TableAdapters managed by a TableAdapterManager must use the same connection s" +
                    "tring.");
        }
        if (((this._versionTableAdapter != null) 
                    && (this.MatchTableAdapterConnection(this._versionTableAdapter.Connection) == false))) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentException("All TableAdapters managed by a TableAdapterManager must use the same connection s" +
                    "tring.");
        }
        if (((this._trailersTableAdapter != null) 
                    && (this.MatchTableAdapterConnection(this._trailersTableAdapter.Connection) == false))) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentException("All TableAdapters managed by a TableAdapterManager must use the same connection s" +
                    "tring.");
        }
        if (((this._trailerSITableAdapter != null) 
                    && (this.MatchTableAdapterConnection(this._trailerSITableAdapter.Connection) == false))) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentException("All TableAdapters managed by a TableAdapterManager must use the same connection s" +
                    "tring.");
        }
        global::System.Data.IDbConnection workConnection = this.Connection;
        if ((workConnection == null)) {
            throw new global::System.ApplicationException("TableAdapterManager contains no connection information. Set each TableAdapterMana" +
                    "ger TableAdapter property to a valid TableAdapter instance.");
        }
        bool workConnOpened = false;
        if (((workConnection.State & global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken) 
                    == global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken)) {
            workConnection.Close();
        }
        if ((workConnection.State == global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)) {
            workConnection.Open();
            workConnOpened = true;
        }
        global::System.Data.IDbTransaction workTransaction = workConnection.BeginTransaction();
        if ((workTransaction == null)) {
            throw new global::System.ApplicationException("The transaction cannot begin. The current data connection does not support transa" +
                    "ctions or the current state is not allowing the transaction to begin.");
        }
        global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::System.Data.DataRow> allChangedRows = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::System.Data.DataRow>();
        global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::System.Data.DataRow> allAddedRows = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::System.Data.DataRow>();
        global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::System.Data.Common.DataAdapter> adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<global::System.Data.Common.DataAdapter>();
        global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, global::System.Data.IDbConnection> revertConnections = new global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, global::System.Data.IDbConnection>();
        int result = 0;
        global::System.Data.DataSet backupDataSet = null;
        if (this.BackupDataSetBeforeUpdate) {
            backupDataSet = new global::System.Data.DataSet();
            backupDataSet.Merge(dataSet);
        }
        try {
            // ---- Prepare for update -----------
            //
            if ((this._consumablesTableAdapter != null)) {
                revertConnections.Add(this._consumablesTableAdapter, this._consumablesTableAdapter.Connection);
                this._consumablesTableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(workConnection));
                this._consumablesTableAdapter.Transaction = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)(workTransaction));
                if (this._consumablesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate) {
                    this._consumablesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Add(this._consumablesTableAdapter.Adapter);
                }
            }
            if ((this._employeesTableAdapter != null)) {
                revertConnections.Add(this._employeesTableAdapter, this._employeesTableAdapter.Connection);
                this._employeesTableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(workConnection));
                this._employeesTableAdapter.Transaction = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)(workTransaction));
                if (this._employeesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate) {
                    this._employeesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Add(this._employeesTableAdapter.Adapter);
                }
            }
            if ((this._holidaysTableAdapter != null)) {
                revertConnections.Add(this._holidaysTableAdapter, this._holidaysTableAdapter.Connection);
                this._holidaysTableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(workConnection));
                this._holidaysTableAdapter.Transaction = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)(workTransaction));
                if (this._holidaysTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate) {
                    this._holidaysTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Add(this._holidaysTableAdapter.Adapter);
                }
            }
            if ((this._servicesTableAdapter != null)) {
                revertConnections.Add(this._servicesTableAdapter, this._servicesTableAdapter.Connection);
                this._servicesTableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(workConnection));
                this._servicesTableAdapter.Transaction = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)(workTransaction));
                if (this._servicesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate) {
                    this._servicesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Add(this._servicesTableAdapter.Adapter);
                }
            }
            if ((this._vehiclesTableAdapter != null)) {
                revertConnections.Add(this._vehiclesTableAdapter, this._vehiclesTableAdapter.Connection);
                this._vehiclesTableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(workConnection));
                this._vehiclesTableAdapter.Transaction = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)(workTransaction));
                if (this._vehiclesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate) {
                    this._vehiclesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Add(this._vehiclesTableAdapter.Adapter);
                }
            }
            if ((this._damagesTableAdapter != null)) {
                revertConnections.Add(this._damagesTableAdapter, this._damagesTableAdapter.Connection);
                this._damagesTableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(workConnection));
                this._damagesTableAdapter.Transaction = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)(workTransaction));
                if (this._damagesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate) {
                    this._damagesTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Add(this._damagesTableAdapter.Adapter);
                }
            }
            if ((this._versionTableAdapter != null)) {
                revertConnections.Add(this._versionTableAdapter, this._versionTableAdapter.Connection);
                this._versionTableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(workConnection));
                this._versionTableAdapter.Transaction = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)(workTransaction));
                if (this._versionTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate) {
                    this._versionTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Add(this._versionTableAdapter.Adapter);
                }
            }
            if ((this._trailersTableAdapter != null)) {
                revertConnections.Add(this._trailersTableAdapter, this._trailersTableAdapter.Connection);
                this._trailersTableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(workConnection));
                this._trailersTableAdapter.Transaction = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)(workTransaction));
                if (this._trailersTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate) {
                    this._trailersTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Add(this._trailersTableAdapter.Adapter);
                }
            }
            if ((this._trailerSITableAdapter != null)) {
                revertConnections.Add(this._trailerSITableAdapter, this._trailerSITableAdapter.Connection);
                this._trailerSITableAdapter.Connection = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)(workConnection));
                this._trailerSITableAdapter.Transaction = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)(workTransaction));
                if (this._trailerSITableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate) {
                    this._trailerSITableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
                    adaptersWithAcceptChangesDuringUpdate.Add(this._trailerSITableAdapter.Adapter);
                }
            }
            // 
            //---- Perform updates -----------
            //
            if ((this.UpdateOrder == UpdateOrderOption.UpdateInsertDelete)) {
                result = (result + this.UpdateUpdatedRows(dataSet, allChangedRows, allAddedRows));
                result = (result + this.UpdateInsertedRows(dataSet, allAddedRows));
            }
            else {
                result = (result + this.UpdateInsertedRows(dataSet, allAddedRows));
                result = (result + this.UpdateUpdatedRows(dataSet, allChangedRows, allAddedRows));
            }
            result = (result + this.UpdateDeletedRows(dataSet, allChangedRows));
            // 
            //---- Commit updates -----------
            //
            workTransaction.Commit();
            if ((0 < allAddedRows.Count)) {
                global::System.Data.DataRow[] rows = new System.Data.DataRow[allAddedRows.Count];
                allAddedRows.CopyTo(rows);
                for (int i = 0; (i < rows.Length); i = (i + 1)) {
                    global::System.Data.DataRow row = rows[i];
                    row.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }
            if ((0 < allChangedRows.Count)) {
                global::System.Data.DataRow[] rows = new System.Data.DataRow[allChangedRows.Count];
                allChangedRows.CopyTo(rows);
                for (int i = 0; (i < rows.Length); i = (i + 1)) {
                    global::System.Data.DataRow row = rows[i];
                    row.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (global::System.Exception ex) {
            workTransaction.Rollback();
            // ---- Restore the dataset -----------
            if (this.BackupDataSetBeforeUpdate) {
                global::System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert((backupDataSet != null));
                dataSet.Clear();
                dataSet.Merge(backupDataSet);
            }
            else {
                if ((0 < allAddedRows.Count)) {
                    global::System.Data.DataRow[] rows = new System.Data.DataRow[allAddedRows.Count];
                    allAddedRows.CopyTo(rows);
                    for (int i = 0; (i < rows.Length); i = (i + 1)) {
                        global::System.Data.DataRow row = rows[i];
                        row.AcceptChanges();
                        row.SetAdded();
                    }
                }
            }
            throw ex;
```

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450675/datatable-internal-index-is-corrupted

Comment: @Matt Switch between the default TableAdapterManager.UpdateOrderOption.InsertUpdateDelete to UpdateInsertDelete may help you

Comment: Looks like you'd find it at `TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(MYPROGRAMDataSetdataSet) in C:\MYPROGRAM\MYPROGRAMDataSet.Designer.cs:line 11240` according to your stacktrace.

Comment: Added TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(MYPROGRAMDataSetdataSet)

Comment: @NaDeRStar YES!! this worked! Thank you, please leave it as an answer

Comment: @Matt awesome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you tried and you know

Switch between the default

```
TableAdapterManager.UpdateOrderOption.InsertUpdateDelete
```

to

```
TableAdapterManager.UpdateOrderOption.UpdateInsertDelete
```